# .net core - Anti-forgery Exception Handling

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, antiforgerytoken

I am trying to handle Antiforgery Exceptions on the client, and I want to show a relevant message to users, but all that I am getting from .Net Core server is **400 Bad Request** response, so I am trying to override that with my own response.

So I added the Filter:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core.Infrastructure;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters;

namespace Website.Filters
{
    public class RedirectAntiforgeryValidationFailedResultFilter : IAlwaysRunResultFilter
    {
        public void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext context)
        {
            if (context.Result is IAntiforgeryValidationFailedResult result)
            {
                [overraid response]
            }
        }

        public void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext context)
        {            
            if (context.Result is IAntiforgeryValidationFailedResult result)
            {
                [overraid response]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and on startup.cs

```
services.AddAntiforgery(options =>
        {
                options.SuppressXFrameOptionsHeader = true;
                options.HeaderName = "......";
                options.Cookie.Name = ".....";
                options.Cookie.Path = "/";
                options.Cookie.Expiration = TimeSpan.FromDays(2);
       });

services.AddMvc(options =>
                options.Filters.Add<RedirectAntiforgeryValidationFailedResultFilter>()
                ).SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
```

I am using this function to set the anti-forgery token for users

```
private static void SetToken(HttpContext context, IAntiforgery antiforgery)
{
    var tokens = antiforgery.GetAndStoreTokens(context);
    context.Response.Cookies.Append("....", tokens.RequestToken, new CookieOptions()
    {
        HttpOnly = false,
        Secure = true,
        MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromDays(2),
        SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict
    });
}
```

**I was never able to reach the [overraid response].**

You can see in the below image that the result is truly AntiforgeryValidationFailedResult and still can't go inside the condition.
[image]

Comment: I could not reproduce your issue.It could get into override response successfully.Could you share more about your Startup.cs and your request action?

Comment: @Rena I updated my question and add some more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using [ApiController] Attribute MVC transforms an error result (a result with status code 400 or higher) to a result with **ProblemDetails**. The **ProblemDetails** type is based on the [RFC 7807 specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7807) for providing machine-readable error details in an HTTP response. you can read more about this [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-2.2#problem-details-for-error-status-codes).

so in order to solve this, I had to suppress map client errors.

```
services.AddMvc(options => 
                options.Filters.Add<RedirectAntiforgeryValidationFailedResultFilter>())
                .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2)
                .ConfigureApiBehaviorOptions(options =>
                {
                    options.SuppressMapClientErrors = true;
                });
```