# How to invoke a custom ResultFilter before ClientErrorResultFilter is executed in ASP.NET 6

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I spent almost a full day debugging why my client can't post any forms, until I found out the anti-forgery mechanism got borked on the client-side and the server just responded with a `400` error, with zero logs or information (turns out anti-forgery validation is logged internally with `Info` level).

So I decided the server needs to special handle this scenario, however [according to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61201994/6389395) I don't really know how to do that (aside from hacking).

Normally I would set up a `IAlwaysRunResultFilter` and check for `IAntiforgeryValidationFailedResult`. Easy.

Except that I use Api Controllers, so by default all results get transformed into [`ProblemDetails`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.apibehavioroptions.suppressmapclienterrors?view=aspnetcore-6.0). So `context.Result` as [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61074642/6389395) is always of type `ObjectResult`. The solution accepted there is to use `options.SuppressMapClientErrors = true;`, however I want to retain this mapping at the end of the pipeline. But if this option isn't set to true, I have no idea how to intercept the `Result` in the pipeline before this transformation.

**So in my case, I want to do something with the result of the anti-forgery validation as mentioned in the linked post, but after that I want to retain the `ProblemDetails` transformation.** But my question is titled generally, as it is about executing filters before the aforementioned client mapping filter.

Through hacking I am able to achieve what I want. If we take a look at the [source code](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/Infrastructure/ClientErrorResultFilter.cs#L13), we can see that the filter I want to precede has an order of `-2000`. So if I register my global filter like this `o.Filters.Add(typeof(MyResultFilter), -2001);`, then the filter shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61074642/6389395) correctly executes before `ClientErrorResultFilter` and thus I can handle the result and retain the transformation after the handling. However I feel like this is just exploiting the open-source-ness of .Net 6 and of course as you can see it's an internal constant, so I have no guarantee the next patch doesn't change it and my code breaks. Surely there must be a proper way to order my filter to run before the api transform.

Comment: Firstly, in web api it is no need use anti-forgery validation. Besides, change the order maybe the only way.

Comment: @Rena depends on how you use the web api. In my case the same origin serves SPA files to the client. If we had a desktop client, we'd have an installer that sets up an api key on the machine for example.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with the order of the model validation filter pipeline. If the model is invalid then it return a 400 before even entering the controller.

For your specific issue, you can prevent the default behavior like this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  services.AddControllers()
    .ConfigureApiBehaviorOptions(o =>
    {
      // Disable `ClientErrorResultFilter`
      o.SuppressMapClientErrors = true;
      
      // ...
    })
    // ...
}
```

More detail here: https://disklosr.com/posts/004-consistent-error-response-format-asp-net-core-web-api/

Comment: Unfortunately I stipulate in the question that I don't want to disable this, just change the order. 4th paragraph.